# Regex for generic but equal prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching for a regular expression that matches and replaces two words within a row with the same but generic prefix and different but definitive suffixes. As a simple example, /x-resses and x-ors/g should match "actresses and actors" and "ancestresses and ancestors". What do I have to replace x with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `x` should be a capture group containing a pattern that matches the accepted character sequence, the second should be a [back reference](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences) to it. For example:

```js
 const regex = /([a-z]+)resses and \1ors/;
 console.log(regex.test('actresses and actors'));
 console.log(regex.test('ancestresses and ancestors'));
 console.log(regex.test('ancestresses and actors'));
```